# What application can edit WebM metadata?

Tags: music, metadata, webm

I have a few hundred WebM files, which include audio and video in one file (WebM is a container format). I want to edit their metadata, like:

- artist who performs the song
- title of the song
- album
- year of publication

I've seen exiftool, but according to their website, they only support reading WebM metadata.

How can I edit these four metadata items?

Comment: Some of this information is incorrect. You are not limited to metadata of title and language. http://wiki.webmproject.org/webm-metadata/global-metadata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ffmpeg, see

http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1870

But at this time it seems that you only can set a title tag or to an audio resp. video stream a language tag

But if the name of the target file in the command line ends with .mkv instead of .webm you can set more metadata, like description tag. But then you have a matroska container.

An example call is:

```
ffmpeg -i tr3d.webm -c copy \
-metadata title="Moin Moin" \
-metadata license="CC-BY-NC-ND" \
-metadata description="Eine Fahrt im TR 09" \
-metadata copyright="Michael Dittmer" \
-metadata genre="Documentation" \
-metadata date_released="2014" \
-metadata url="http://www.pro-transrapid.org" \
-metadata artist="GFM-eV" \
-metadata publisher="Pro-Transrapid" \ 
-metadata:s:a:0 language="Spanish" \
tr3d_tagged.mkv
```

Answer (score 4):

mkvpropedit works as webm is a subset of mkv:

- https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvpropedit.html

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix
```

Edit: examples

```
mkvpropedit --edit info --set "title=FOO S01E01" foo.mkv
mkvpropedit -s date=(stat --format=%Y foo.webm) foo.webm
```

Comment: Any info how to add title, artist, publisher, language, date? It seems to only accept some XML that I see no example of.

Comment: I found an example or two in my history, haven't used it recently.

Comment: works, webm seems to support few tags only

Comment: The supported tags are documented here: https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/#tagging